# What is @ as part of main function argument

Tags: arrays, string, arguments, program-entry-point, vala

I see following code on [this page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40812/radioascii-elements-output-the-elements-of-the-periodic-table-while-slowly-losi/40841#40841):

```
int main(string[]@a)
   {print("Manganese");return 0;}
```

Why it is not following:

```
int main(string[] args)
   {print("Manganese");return 0;}
```

What is difference between `string[]@a` and `string[] args` and when is it used?

Comment: `What is difference` - the [rules of the golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40812) say the banned character should be used, and the OP wanted to ban the `@`, so had to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` symbol is used to prefix identifier names when the name either begins with a digit, or is a keyword.

> Identifier names may be any combination of letters ([a-z], [A-Z]), underscores and digits. However, to define or refer to an identifier with a name that either starts with a digit or is a keyword, you must prefix it with the '@' character. This character is not considered a part of the name. For example, you can name a method foreach by writing @foreach, even though this is a reserved Vala keyword. You can omit the '@' character when it can be unambiguously interpreted as an identifier name, such as in "foo.foreach()".

See: [Vala Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial) under the Syntax section

To answer your question "What is difference between `string[]@a` and `string[] args` and when is it used?", well, not much. Other than simply using the variable name `a` instead of `args`, it's not a compiler error to use the `@` symbol in front of other variable names, even when the criteria above aren't met (although certainly not good practice). The author could safely prefix the variable `a` as `@a`, even though it's not the normal usage of the prefix.

Comment: Very well explained. This is exactly what I was asking.